# Sitecore 7.2 Package designer & Installation wizard error

Tags: package-designer

Either using the installation wizard or package designer has started throwing an error.

We have had no web config changes or code releases. Any potential pointers on what the culprit could be?

**Package Designer**

```
Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load '../sitecore/shell/applications/tools/installer/designer'
```

**Installation Manager**

```
Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load '../sitecore/shell/applications/tools/installer/installationwizard'
```

**EDIT**

So, after an app pool refresh I started receiving the error "The file exists".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128934/discussion-on-question-by-sean-t-sitecore-7-2-package-designer-installation-wi).

Comment: Which package have you installed?

Comment: It's a content package via the package designer, taken from our staging instance to put onto our production cm server @QuachNguyen